# getting current user credentials and using it in a script for mapping network path

Tags: vbscript

I want to map a network drive and wanted to know if it's possible that I can use the username and password of the user running the script while making the connection

```
NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "",FolderPath,False,UserName,Password
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MapNetworkDrive` automatically uses the logged-in user's credentials when parameters 4 and 5 (username and password) are omitted.

Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6):

> *strUser*
>   Optional. String value indicating the user name. You must supply this argument if you are mapping a network drive using the credentials of someone other than the current user.
>
> *strPassword*
>   Optional. String value indicating the user password. You must supply this argument if you are mapping a network drive using the credentials of someone other than the current user.

Simply running

```
NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", FolderPath, False
```

should work fine.